# Call a function for each row of a dataframe in pyspark[non pandas]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

There is a function in pyspark:

```
def sum(a,b):
    c=a+b
    return c
```

It has to be run on each record of a very very large dataframe using spark sql:

```
x = sum(df.select["NUM1"].first()["NUM1"], df.select["NUM2"].first()["NUM2"])
```

But this would run it only for the first record of the df and not for all rows.
I understand it could be done using a lambda, but I am not able to code it in the desired way.

In reality; c would be a dataframe and the function would be doing a lot of spark.sql stuff and return it. I  would have to call that function for each row.
I guess, I will try to pick it up using this `sum(a,b)` as an analogy.

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
|     NUM1 |     NUM2 |    XYZ    |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|      10  |     20   |      HELLO|                                    
|      90  |     60   |      WORLD|
|      50  |     45   |      SPARK|
+----------+----------+-----------+


+----------+----------+-----------+------+
|     NUM1 |     NUM2 |    XYZ    | VALUE|
+----------+----------+-----------+------+
|      10  |     20   |      HELLO|30    |                                     
|      90  |     60   |      WORLD|150   |
|      50  |     45   |      SPARK|95    |
+----------+----------+-----------+------+

Python: 3.7.4
Spark: 2.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .withColumn function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
df.show()
+----+----+-----+
|NUM1|NUM2|  XYZ|
+----+----+-----+
|  10|  20|HELLO|
|  90|  60|WORLD|
|  50|  45|SPARK|
+----+----+-----+

def mysum(a,b):
  return a + b

spark.udf.register("mysumudf", mysum, LongType())

df2 = df.withColumn("VALUE", mysum(col("NUM1"),col("NUM2"))

df2.show()
+----+----+-----+-----+
|NUM1|NUM2|  XYZ|VALUE|
+----+----+-----+-----+
|  10|  20|HELLO|   30|
|  90|  60|WORLD|  150|
|  50|  45|SPARK|   95|
+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Solution in python pls. $ is not there in python and this is creating trouble for me

Comment: I will try sum(df['NUM1'],df['NUM2']) . In reality, i have to call this function in select statement itself. That should not be a problem. It would be select sum(df['NUM1'],df['NUM2']) from abc. That should work i guess

Comment: In select statement it is throwing error. df['NUM1'] is printed as Column<b'NUM1'> which is wrong. I want this to be the actual value of this column. And the same needs to be applied for all the records of the df on which select is running

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what the withColumn function is for, it applies a function to every row, on selected column. I corrected the use of $

Answer (score 2):

We can do it in below ways and while registering udf 3rd argument that is return type is not mandatory.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(10,20,'HELLO'),(90,60,'WORLD'),(50,45,'SPARK')],['NUM1','NUM2','XYZ'])
df1.show()
df2=df1.withColumn('VALUE',F.expr('NUM1 + NUM2'))
df2.show(3,False)
+----+----+-----+-----+
|NUM1|NUM2|XYZ  |VALUE|
+----+----+-----+-----+
|10  |20  |HELLO|30   |
|90  |60  |WORLD|150  |
|50  |45  |SPARK|95   |
+----+----+-----+-----+


(or)

def sum(c1,c2):
    return c1+c2
spark.udf.register('sum_udf1',sum)
df2=df1.withColumn('VALUE',F.expr("sum_udf1(NUM1,NUM2)"))
df2.show(3,False)
+----+----+-----+-----+
|NUM1|NUM2|XYZ  |VALUE|
+----+----+-----+-----+
|10  |20  |HELLO|30   |
|90  |60  |WORLD|150  |
|50  |45  |SPARK|95   |
+----+----+-----+-----+
(or)

sum_udf2=F.udf(lambda x,y: x+y)
df2=df1.withColumn('VALUE',sum_udf2('NUM1','NUM2'))
df2.show(3,False)
+----+----+-----+-----+
|NUM1|NUM2|XYZ  |VALUE|
+----+----+-----+-----+
|10  |20  |HELLO|30   |
|90  |60  |WORLD|150  |
|50  |45  |SPARK|95   |
+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below simple approach:**

**1. Import pyspark.sql functions**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

**2. Use F.expr() function**

```
df.withColumn("VALUE",F.expr("NUM1+NUM2")<br>
```